# jsDoc - Don't exclude methods that are marked as @private

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

Currently jsDoc is excluding my class methods that are marked as @private, which in turn is not generating documentation for those methods. Our documentation is only used internally, so I still want the methods to show, so other developers are aware.

Can I just add property to the `jsdoc.json` file to still display methods, properites, etc... regardless if marked @private?

Comment: Did you run with `--access "all"`? Default is to exclude private symbols: https://jsdoc.app/about-commandline.html

Comment: No I haven't, I was wondering if it was possible to add it to the jsdoc config file. This does solve my needs so I'll upvote your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default JSDoc excludes private symbols (those annotated with `@private`), you can include them either via the command line:

```
jsdoc --access "all" …
```

Or via the configuration file:

```json
{
  "access": "all"
}
```

Comment: Awesome! For those who add this to their config file it does go under the "opts" object.

Comment: @leroyjenkinss24 Oops. Please feel free to edit this answer.